# Concatenate ints in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, concatenation, stringstream

As part of a homework assignment I need to concatenate certain values in an array in C++. So, for example if I have:

```
int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4}
```

I may need at some point to concatenate v[1] -> v[4] so that I get an int with the value 1234.

I got it working using stringstream, by appending the values onto the stringstream and then converting back to an integer. However, throughout the program there will eventually be about 3 million different permutations of v[] passed to my toInt() function, and the stringstream seems rather expensive (at least when dealing with that many values). it's working, but very slow and I'm trying to do whatever I can to optimize it.

Is there a more optimal way to concatenate ints in an array in C++? I've done some searching and nearly everywhere seems to just suggest using stringstream (which works, but seems to be slowing my program down a lot).

EDIT: Just clarifying, I do need the result to be an int.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if one of the ints is greater than 9? Or negative?

Comment: What does "concatenate" mean? Do you want strings or numbers? What happened to multiplying by 10?

Comment: @Mat - the values in the array are always between 0 and 9.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

Comment: @Kerrek SB: the eventual result needs to be an int

Comment: I understand that, but I specified what I needed in my initial question. "...so that I get an int with the value 1234". Sorry if I'm not clear enough or if I don't have a firm grasp on all of the technical details of a problem yet -- I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @Nate: I'm very sorry, I had misunderstood. The answer is "place-value system", and you ought to be able to do it for any number base. (TommyN's answer does it base-10.)

Comment: "Concatenating ints" is definitely the wrong expression for this. You're concatenating _digits_, decimal digits. If these turn up in you're program as `int`s, then that's very ineffective to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications leftaroundabout and Kerrek SB, I do appreciate it. Helps me learn. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pseudo code for a simple solution:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i=0; i < len(v); i++)
{
  result = result*10 + v[i];
}
```

Large arrays will bomb out due to int size overflow.

Comment: Perhaps a float or double would fair better?

Comment: My values never get bigger than 5 digits in this program, so the ints work fine. And this is what I just ended up implementing, and it works great! Cut my execution time in half.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
int result = (((v[1])*10+v[2])*10+v[3])*10+v[4];
```

If the number of elements is variable rather than a fixed number, I'm sure you can spot a pattern here that can be applied in a loop.

Comment: @Joni Thanks so much; this helped.

Answer (score 1):

All are integers. Shouldn't you do the following.

```
//if you want to concatenate v[1] and v[4]
int concatenated;
concatenated = v[1]*10+v[4];
//If you want to concatenate all
concatenated = 0;
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    concatenated = concatenated*10+v[i];
```

the output would be an integer ( not a string)

Comment: Yeah, I need the output to be an int. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember ASCII codes?

```
char concat[vSize+1];
concat[vSize] = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < vSize; i++) {
    concat[i] = (v[i] % 10) & 0x30;
}
```

Comment: Oops, actually, now that I read your post more carefully, I'm wrong. I thought you wanted a string. Refer to others for the correct answer.

Comment: I think you mean `| 0x30`, but still, `+ '0'` would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do:

1. Make sure that you compile with `-O3` (Or equivalent compiler optimization).
2. Do you generate the values in the vector yourself? If so, try changing `toInt()` function to accept a simple pointer type.
3. Write the conversion yourself (Browser code : may not even compile - u get the idea though):

   ```
   char* toInt(int* values, size_t length)
   {
     int *end = values + sizeof(int)*length;
     int *cur = values;

     char* buf = new char[length + 1]

     for(char* out = buf;cur < end;++cur, ++buf)
     {
         *out = (char)*cur + '0';
     }
     *buf = '\0';
     return buf;
   }
   ```

Comment: -1 That's very C-ish. It's outrightly dangerous to return a C-style string allocated with `new` in C++, because chances are the caller will forget to delete the string, which makes a _really_ problematic memory leak when the function is called millions of times.

Comment: @leftaroundabout : Dont know why you'd downvote it just because the code is C-ish. The questioner is asking how to improve performance of a very simple function. I would not write an application this way but for a piece of homework I definitely will use this.

Comment: If it _was_ a simple a simple and effective performance boost I wouldn't have downvoted it. But your code would compile to nothing faster than what any decent compiler would make of the much safer _and easier_ variant with `std::vector`/`std::string`s. Change it to use those, and I'll upvote.